# New Azure AD Connect Cloud agent status inactive

Tags: azure, agent

Installed 2 different member servers with Azure AD Connect cloud agents both have an inactive status.

I confirmed;

1. Both installs complete successfully
2. Proxy settings are off
3. Since the Azure port test URL is no longer working I manually tested several of the URLs listed on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-safelist-urls?tabs=public-cloud, they were working

**Here is a snippet from the local/server logs;**

```html
    AADConnectProvisioningAgent.exe Error: 0 : Service bootstrap request failed with exception: 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://[UUID].syncfabric.bootstrap.his.msappproxy.net/ConnectorBootstrap that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStreamAsyncResult.CompleteGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult result)
```

When it says "the remote server returned an error: 407 proxy authentication", is that MS end or our end?

Comment: I am waiting to hear from our proxy administrator but the server is set BYPASS the proxy server and I am not seeing any credential prompts.

And using a browser to visit some of the listed domains seem fine load without issue.

Comment: Tested the invoke cmd and it returns 200. (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-connectivity)

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://adminwebservice.microsoftonline.com/ProvisioningService.svc

StatusCode        : 200

Answer (score 0):

After trying numerous updates to the machine.config file, as with most MS products there are 100 different options to "try" to get the proxy settings right. None worked even after restarting the service.

We eventually gave up on that and manually set the proxy itself to allow the Azrue AD agent computer/IP to skip/bypass authentication and it connected successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).